# Why does a sign-in prompt show up when I access a website over https?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, windows-authentication, iis-8

I have created a website and hosted it in IIS Server on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have set the authentication to be Windows Authentication. When the user who has logged into the domain tries accessing the website, everything works fine and no prompt is shown to the user.

Now I need to serve this website over https. I have purchased the certificate and added it to the website and have set up the SSL binding. When the user tries accessing the website now (using Google Chrome), he/she gets a "Sign in" prompt like this:

[image]

Why does this happen? Is there a setting in IIS I can change so that the user is not prompted?

I cannot not find documentation from Microsoft on how is this supposed to happen but I was under impression that the browser would pass the user's credentials to the IIS server without prompting the user to enter them.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password IE would prompt as the URL contains periods, and you need to modify security settings accordingly. Google Chrome seems to follow the same approach, and you might check its documentation to learn more. Generally speaking, the solution is on browser side, and nothing is needed to change on IIS.

Answer (score 2):

With the information from [this post](https://sysadminspot.com/windows/google-chrome-and-ntlm-auto-logon-using-windows-authentication/), I found the solution for Google Chrome (67.0.3396.99). Apparently Chrome (as well as IE) reads the settings from Internet Options in Control Panel.

Here are the steps to remove the Sign in prompt:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Internet Options
2. Go to Security tab and select Trusted sites zone:

   [image]
3. Click Sites button and make sure that you have your website's URL added to the list. Add it if you do not see it.
4. Close the Trusted sites popup.
5. In the Internet Properties dialogue, click Custom level… button

   [image]
6. Scroll down to User Authentication section and make sure that you have “Automatic logon with current user name and password” option selected.

   [image]
7. Click OK button to close the security settings dialogue.
8. Click Yes button on the Warning popup.
9. Click OK button to close the Internet Properties dialogue.

Comment: Thank you. This answer helped me.